# как присвоить переменной значениие кортежа без их дальнейшей "синхронизации"

Tags: python, list, копирование

вот код:

```
a = [1, 5]
b = a
b.pop(1)
print(a)
```

Программа выводит: [1]

а мне необходимо чтобы переменную "a" это не затрагивало

есть такой вариант:

```
a = [1, 5]
b = eval(str(a))
b.pop(1)
print(a)
```

и всё работает хорошо, но это скорее-всего плохой вариант, есть-ли какие-нибудь другие ваианты?

Comment: `b = a.copy()` вот так

Comment: спасибо, так быстро!

Comment: А где, собственно, кортеж?

Answer (score 1):

Скопировать список можно разными способами:

1. метод `.copy()` (как писал **@gord1402** в комментариях):

   ```py
   b = a.copy()
   ```
2. срез:

   ```py
   b = a[:]
   ```
3. вызов конструктора `list`:

   ```py
   b = list(a)
   ```